# Order latest records by timestamp in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, time-series

I'm trying to display the latest values from a list of sensors. The list should also be sortable by the time-stamp.

I tried two different approaches. I included the update time of the sensor in the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE sensors (
    customerid int,
    sensorid int,
    changedate timestamp,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY (customerid, changedate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (changedate DESC);
```

Then I can select the list like this:

```
select * from sensors where customerid=0 order by changedate desc;
```

which results in this:

```
 customerid | changedate               | sensorid | value
------------+--------------------------+----------+-------
          0 | 2015-07-10 12:46:53+0000 |        1 |     2
          0 | 2015-07-10 12:46:52+0000 |        1 |     1
          0 | 2015-07-10 12:46:52+0000 |        0 |     2
          0 | 2015-07-10 12:46:26+0000 |        0 |     1
```

The problem is, I don't get only the latest results, but all the old values too.

If I remove the changedate from the primary key, the select fails all together.

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Order by is currently only supported on the clustered columns of the PRIMARY KEY, got changedate"
```

Updating the sensor values is also no option:

```
update overview set changedate=unixTimestampOf(now()), value = '5' where customerid=0 and sensorid=0;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY part changedate found in SET part"
```

This fails because changedate is part of the primary key.

Is there any possible way to store only the latest values from each sensor and also keep the table ordered by the time-stamp?

**Edit:**
In the meantime I tried another approach, to only storing the latest value.

I used this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sensors (
    customerid int,
    sensorid int,
    changedate timestamp,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY (customerid, sensorid, changedate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (changedate DESC);
```

Before inserting the latest value, I would delete all old values

```
DELETE FROM sensors WHERE customerid=? and sensorid=?;
```

But this fails because `changedate` is NOT part of the WHERE clause.

Comment: This seems like the classic retrieving the last record in each group problem. I.e. get the latest reading for each sensorID.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is, I don't get only the latest results, but all the old values too.

Since you are storing in a CLUSTERING ORDER of DESC, it will always be very easy to get the latest records, all you need to do is add 'LIMIT' to your query, i.e.:

```
select * from sensors where customerid=0 order by changedate desc limit 10;
```

Would return you at most 10 records with the highest changedate.  Even though you are using limit, you are still guaranteed to get the latest records since your data is ordered that way.

> If I remove the changedate from the primary key, the select fails all together.

This is because you cannot order on a column that is not the clustering key(s) (the secondary part of the primary key) except maybe with a secondary index, which I would not recommend.

> Updating the sensor values is also no option

Your update query is failing because it is not legal to include part of the primary key in 'set'.  To make this work all you need to do is update your query to include changedate in the where clause, i.e.:

```
update overview set value = '5' and sensorid = 0 where customerid=0 and changedate=unixTimestampOf(now())
```

> Is there any possible way to store only the latest values from each sensor and also keep the table ordered by the time-stamp?

You can do this by creating a separate table named 'latest_sensor_data' with the same table definition with exception to the primary key.   The primary key will now be 'customerid, sensorid' so you can only have 1 record per sensor.  The process of creating separate tables is called [denormalization](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/share/glossary/gloss_denormalization.html) and is a common use pattern particularly in Cassandra data modeling.  When you insert sensor data you would now insert data into both 'sensors' and 'latest_sensor_data'.

```
CREATE TABLE latest_sensor_data (
  customerid int,
  sensorid int,
  changedate timestamp,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (customerid, sensorid)
);
```

In cassandra 3.0 ['materialized views'](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) will be introduced which will make this unnecessary as you can use materialized views to accomplish this for you.

Now doing the following query:

```
select * from latest_sensor_data where customerid=0
```

Will give you the latest value for every sensor for that customer.

I would recommend renaming 'sensors' to 'sensor_data' or 'sensor_history' to make it more clear what the data is.  Additionally you should change the primary key to 'customerid, changedate, sensorid' as that would allow you to have multiple sensors at the same date (which seems possible).

Comment: Another note, if you want more then the latest value (i.e. the last 10 values), it gets more difficult.  In C* 2.2 you could use user defined aggregates to have cassandra grab the 10 'newest' values for each sensor by customer for your sensor table.  You could also look into something like using the spark-cassandra-connector to compute this for you occasionally.

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is, that I loose the ability to sort by `changedate`.

Comment: I'm proposing 2 tables, one with a clustering key on changedate ('sensor_history' table) and another clustered on sensorid.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach looks reasonable.  If you add "limit 1" to your query, you would only get the latest result, or limit 2 to see the latest 2 results, etc.

If you want to automatically remove old values from the table, you can specify a TTL (Time To Live) for data points when you do the insert.  So if you wanted to keep data points for 10 days, you could do this by adding "USING TTL 864000" on your insert statements.  Or you could set a default TTL for the entire table.

Comment: I cannot use TTL here, because there is no guaranteed time-span, where a sensor reports values. It may stay silent for days, weeks or even months. But I still need to retain the latest value.

Comment: I think the OP wanted the latest for each sensorID.